# Breaking deal with Dark One

Tags: once-upon-a-time

In 'Once Upon a Time' the people made a deal with dark one and signed a contract.

What happens when anyone breaks the deal? Is there any harm if the deal is broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we can see from the below example, there is no penalty (besides possibly drawing Rumple's ire) for breaking a deal - the deals that Rumple makes are usually to fullfil the other person's desires, while benefiting Rumple in the long run:

- Anna's deal with Rumple for information on her parents (Season 4) - Rumple asks her to tip the 'poison' into the Wizard's cup, which she doesn't do

Viewing the below source shows a list of all deals, including outcome

Source: [Once Upon A Time Wikia](http://onceuponatime.wikia.com/wiki/Rumplestiltskin_and_Mr._Gold's_Deals)